# Jasmine node - All matchers are undefined?

Tags: node.js, jasmine

hoping this one will be an easy slam dunk for someone. I'm driving myself crazy here.

I'm trying to run jasmine from the command line. For some reason any and all matchers are failing to work...

Here is my test_spec.js

```
describe('whatever', function() {

 it('whatevs', function(done) {
   expect(200).toEqual(200);
   done();
 })

});
```

From the command line I run

```
$ jasmine test_spec.js
```

And here is the output

```
Started
F

Failures:
1) whatever whatevs
  Message:
    TypeError: expect(...).toEqual is not a function
  Stack:
    TypeError: expect(...).toEqual is not a function
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dolokhov/Work/EcoEverything/supreme/test_spec.js:4:17)
        at clearDB (/Users/dolokhov/Work/EcoEverything/supreme/spec/helpers/db_utils.js:21:12)
        at /Users/dolokhov/Work/EcoEverything/supreme/spec/helpers/db_utils.js:29:14
        at /Users/dolokhov/Work/EcoEverything/supreme/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:284:19
        at open (/Users/dolokhov/Work/EcoEverything/supreme/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:511:17)
        at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (/Users/dolokhov/Work/EcoEverything/supreme/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:521:5)
        at /Users/dolokhov/Work/EcoEverything/supreme/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:483:11
        at /Users/dolokhov/Work/EcoEverything/supreme/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:71:5
        at /Users/dolokhov/Work/EcoEverything/supreme/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:234:5
        at connectHandler (/Users/dolokhov/Work/EcoEverything/supreme/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:306:7)
        at g (events.js:260:16)
        at emitOne (events.js:77:13)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 0.048 seconds
```

node version 4.4.0

jasmine-node version 1.14.3

Comment: help? Maybe give up and reinstall all my node modules?

Comment: Perhaps you're using [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) instead of [jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine). Jasmine has node support out of the box now. jasmine-node is pretty old...

Comment: to be honest I might have both installed. Will clean up and try again

Comment: and that didn't work either. removed all jasmine modules and reinstalled both locally and globally, still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Node.js 4.4.0, here are the commands I ran to get your file to work:

```
npm install -g jasmine
jasmine init
jasmine test_spec.js
```

If that doesn't work for you, some possibilities might be:

- Maybe the `jasmine init` step was skipped or needs to be re-run.
- Maybe there is a different `jasmine` executable in your path that is getting run before the one that is associated with the `jasmine` npm module.

Comment: hey! thanks for the help. I might have the wrong executable in my path. will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so totally new answer here.

Turns out it had nothing to do with my jasmine install. Instead I had a residual spec_helper.js file left over from when I was using chai and mocha. I had moved it into spec/helpers so Jasmine was loading it automatically. It included such wonderful lines of code such as

```
global.expect = chai.expect()
```

Which broke all my Jasmine matchers.....

So yeah no problem with Jasmine here. I was just setting global vars that collided with Jasmine! Argh!